# jQuery XML: Count number of leaf nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

How can I count the number of leaf nodes coming off a particular XML node using jQuery?
The XML in question looks similar to this.  I want all leaf nodes coming off the `<Errors>` node.

```
<Errors>
    <ErrorParentCat>
        <ErrorTag/>
        <ErrorTag2/>
    </ErrorParentCat>
</Errors>
```

In this example I want `<ErrorTag/>` and `<ErrorTag2/>` counted only.  The result should therefore be `2`.  Also `<ErrorParentCat>` is an example tag, there could be many within `<Errors>` with different names.

Once I have the number I would like a list of these leaf nodes too, if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have an `XMLDocument` named `xml`:

```
var $xml = $(xml),
    count = $xml.find('*').filter(function ()
    {
        return $(this).children().length === 0;
    }).length;
console.log(count);
```

You can also just pass the XML string directly to the jQuery function:

```
var $xml = $('<Errors><ErrorParentCat><ErrorTag/><ErrorTag2/></ErrorParentCat></Errors>');
// the rest is the same
```

[jsfiddle demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/7Ntrt/)

---

***Edit*** you said you wanted a list of those leaf nodes. In the code above, you've already got them:

```
var $xml = /* whatever */,
    $leafNodes = $xml.find('*').filter(function ()
    {
        return $(this).children().length === 0;
    }),
    count = $leafNodes.length;
```

***Edit #2*** as Tim Down has pointed out (see comments below), you cannot just pass the XML string to `$()` in IE (!@#$ing IE). You should use the jQuery 1.5 function [`$.parseXML()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) to parse an arbitrary well-formed XML string into an `XMLDocument`:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML('<Errors><ErrorParentCat><ErrorTag/><ErrorTag2/></ErrorParentCat></Errors>'),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc);
/* the rest is unchanged */
```

[new jsfiddle demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/vM9Wx/)

Comment: Cheers for the answer, I modified the code myself before I saw your update :)

Comment: @Chris: I figured it wasn't beyond you, but I try to answer as clearly as possible. You're welcome.

Comment: No, you can't pass XML directly into the jQuery function. jQuery assumes that it's dealing with HTML and does not parse it as XML. However, jQuery 1.5 does have a `parseXML()` method: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: @Tim: you might notice that the jsfiddle example I posted works correctly, and does exactly what you say won't work. That said, you're probably right about it being better to use `$.parseXML()`.

Comment: @Matt: Not in IE it doesn't. Seriously, recommending using `$()` for parsing XML is bad: it's not designed for it, it doesn't work and jQuery now provides a function to do it.

Comment: @Tim: I only tested it in Chrome; I'll update my answer and jsfiddle to use `$.parseXML()`.

Comment: @Matt: Thanks. It's not really IE's fault: there's no reason why it should work, given that random XML elements are not generally valid within HTML DOMs.

Answer (score 1):

Loads of ways to do this:

```
var countThem = 0;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'blahblah.xml',
        dataType: ($.browser.msie) ? "text/xml" : "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            var xml2 = load_xml(xml);
            $(xml2).find('Errors').each(function(){
                $(xml2).find('ErrorParentCat').each(function(){
                    alert($(this).text()); //alert the contents
                    countThem++;
                });
            });
            alert(countThem); //alert the total number
        }
    });
```

and the XML load function:

```
function load_xml(msg) {   
     if ( typeof msg == 'string') {
        if (window.DOMParser)//Firefox
          {
            parser=new DOMParser();
            data=parser.parseFromString(text,"text/xml");
        }else{ // Internet Explorer
           data=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
           data.async="false";
           data.loadXML(msg);
       }
     } else {
        data = msg;
     }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I should have specified that `ErrorParentCat` was an example, there may be many

Comment: Thanks though, its nice apart from that little bit :)